# How to remove single quotes from string in Swift?

Tags: swift, urlencode

I receive value from API response like below

```
{
    "first_name" = "active EQ 'true'";
}
```

I need to send that value as a query parameter in another API. But when sending the request I see that URL is not being encoded. I am expecting that `active EQ 'true'` should be URL encoded as `active%20EQ%20%27true%27`.

I tried `addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed) and it resulted in "active%20EQ%20\'true\'`. I see backslash is being added as escape character but not encoding as expected.

```
let k = "active EQ 'true'"
let j = k.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
print("j is \(j)")
```

I expected the output as `active%20EQ%20%27true%27`, but the actual output is `active%20EQ%20\'true\'`

Comment: The single quotes are *not* backslash-escaped in `j`, that is an artifact of printing an optional. Try `print(j!)` .

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I didn't notice that. That removed backslash. Any thoughts on how that single quotes can be encoded.

Comment: Are you sure that they *need* to be escaped in a query?

Comment: `.urlQueryAllowed` is not the character set to be used when encoding URL parameters. You have to create your own character set.

Comment: @MartinR The API request is being success even not escaped. But was wondering why they are not being encoded.

Comment: @Sulthan seems here  ```URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet     "#%<>[\]^`{|}``` are the allowed characters in `.urlQueryAllowed`. I think single quotes will be allowed as query parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Omit " ' " from your string first. Check following code :

```
let k = "active EQ 'true' "
let i = k.replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "")
let j = i.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
print("j is \(j!)")
```

Comment: Thanks, Nahid. I tried this, but was looking for if there is any generic method we can use instead of replacing them,

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I checked it and its working fine.

```
let k = "active EQ 'true'"
let j = escape(k)
print("j is \(j)")

func escape(_ string: String) -> String {
        let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@" // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
        let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

        var allowedCharacterSet = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
        allowedCharacterSet.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")

        return string.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: allowedCharacterSet) ?? string
    }
```

> **Result:** j is active%20EQ%20%27true%27

Comment: Thanks, Parth. But we are not using Almofire and we need to pass them as query string as per requirement.

Comment: You can check the Alamofire framework. Find out how to encode as per your requirement. @user3584797

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all suggestions and by EOD I don't want to encode single quotes as the API is working fine with that and value to API should be sent with single quotes only. I was just trying to know the possibilities of encoding this type of strings.